# indenting savehist-file in Emacs

Tags: emacs, indentation, pretty-print

I am using https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/savehist.el for saving the history of `filesets-data`. Yet in my `savehist-file` all sets of files are listed in one single very long line. Is there a way of indenting or, more generally, formatting the output so that it is more readable (and, potentially, more easily modified manually)?

Comment: You're asking for pretty-printing. Yes, you could write a bit of code to force pretty-printing in the region that gets written to the file with `write-region` in function `savehist-save`. But there's really no reason to do that, is there? You can use `C-h v filesets-data` to see the value pretty-printed. Do you really need it pretty printed in the file also?

Comment: I wasn't aware of `C-h v filesets-data`, @Drew. Thanks! Yet even with that function, the (many!) files (which in my case include absolute paths!) in each set are all printed on one single long line. I personally do not find that very readable. My reason for printing `filesets-data` would be to be able to identify at one glance which files belong to which project. That would be much easier if the printing were in standard elisp format, including new lines and indents. Maybe using `DiredPlus` is an option, as mentioned in [this emacswiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FileSets#h5o-4)?

Comment: No, Dired+ won't help with your question. And the pretty-print functions won't help either, I'm afraid.

Comment: Too bad, but no shame. ;-)